# Laravel permission denied for bootstrap/cache/packages.phpkC7P4V failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vagrant

I am posting this because I have all possible solution from the stackoverflow answers.

> file_put_contents(/var/www/project-name/bootstrap/cache/packages.phpaVsm7S):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied

I am having this error of permission denied. I have recently put the project in virtualbox using vagrant.

I have done following,

sudo chmod -R 777 bootstrap
composer dump-autoload

This is my user on vagrant

> vagrant@ubuntu-xenial:

Still no luck.

Please, help me. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks @TalhaF. It's worked for me without --force.